# Ubuntu - Booting black screen with purple border

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, bootloader, grub2

I have a problem when I boot the pc. After the installation of Ubuntu, a black screen with a purple box appears without letting me see the choices of GRUB. The screen then becomes black and Ubuntu starts booting. Ubuntu is the only OS installed but it's quite annoying because I can't see the option of the bootloader.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why not ask askubuntu?

Comment: I tried also there but maybe here someone can help me.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution?